# Checking a condition for the Dataframe within 2 years time in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a dataframe as below. I need an extra column to check if each client has had default = 1 in the past 2 years. For the following customer with ID = 1, for the first 4 rows should return 0, while for the rest of the rows it should return 1 as the default = 1 on November, 2011 and the latest date for this client is March 2013 which is within 2 years.

```
   cust_ID, date, default

   1       2/1/11   0

   1       3/1/11   0

   1       6/1/11   0

   1       9/1/11   0

   1       11/1/11  1

   1       12/1/11  0

   1       3/1/12   0

   1       5/1/12   0

   1       8/1/12   0

   1       9/1/12   0

   1       10/1/12  0

   1       11/1/12  0

   1       12/1/12  0

   1       1/1/13   0

   1       2/1/13   0

   1       3/1/13   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need chain 2 masks - check if date is less like maximal date with subtract 2 years and then if cumulative sums are not `0`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%m/%d/%y')

m1=df.groupby('cust_ID')['date'].transform('max').sub(pd.DateOffset(years=2)).lt(df['date'])

m2=df.groupby('cust_ID')['default'].cumsum().ne(0)

df['new'] = (m1 & m2).astype(int)
print (df)
    cust_ID       date  default  new
0         1 2011-02-01        0    0
1         1 2011-03-01        0    0
2         1 2011-06-01        0    0
3         1 2011-09-01        0    0
4         1 2011-11-01        1    1
5         1 2011-12-01        0    1
6         1 2012-03-01        0    1
7         1 2012-05-01        0    1
8         1 2012-08-01        0    1
9         1 2012-09-01        0    1
10        1 2012-10-01        0    1
11        1 2012-11-01        0    1
12        1 2012-12-01        0    1
13        1 2013-01-01        0    1
14        1 2013-02-01        0    1
15        1 2013-03-01        0    1
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution with not exactly two years but 2 * 365,25 days:

```
my_df.set_index('date', inplace=True) # set the date as index
my_df['result'] = (my_df['default'].rolling('731D').sum > 0).astype(int)
```